# Первая музыка не воспроизводится (MediaPlayer)

Tags: android, mediaplayer

**Приложение** - перелистывание картинок (ViewPager) с озвучкой (MediaPlayer) на каждую картинку.
**Проблема** - когда главная активити вызывает дочернюю с первой картинкой, музыки нет, при перелистывании вперед-назад все картинки озвучиваются, в том числе и первая. Лишь при первом вызове первая картинка не озвучивается.
**Намерение** - "Озвучить наконец первую страницу".

Код:

```
  package com.mycompany.myapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static MediaPlayer mp=null;
ViewPager viewPager;
FirstCustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
private int[] mAudio=new int[]{R.raw.sound_11,R.raw.sound_12,R.raw.sound_13};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new FirstCustomSwipeAdapter((this));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnPageListener);

}
public OnPageChangeListener mOnPageListener=new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mp !=null){
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(FirstActivity.this,mAudio[position]);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
};
}
```

Comment: `mOnPageListener.onPageSelected(0);` в onCreate пробовали?

Comment: Попробовала     `mOnPageListener.onPageSelected(0);` в onCreate  -заработало! С OnLoad не пробовала, может тоже заработает. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Добавь обработчик OnLoad для активити, и туда закинь код, который будет озвучивать первую картинку. Т.е идея в том, что бы вызывать озвучку в тот момент, когда активити будет создана, зарегистрирована и отрисована пользователю, там точно есть соответсвующий event для этого.

Comment: Или OnDraw, как там это в android'ах называется.